# send back Date objects in nodejs NOT strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am  using nodejs with express.
I would like to be able to send Date objects directly as a result but node/express seems to convert it automatically to String.
I could parse the string client-side but why should I ?

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(new Date()); 
});
```

Side-question : happy to get a jsFiddle with a node.js + Express functioning app. For some reason I can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using serialize-javascript https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript.